# When can DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE (‘TokenAndPermUserStore’) hang in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are running production DB servers on SQL Server 2005 and we ran into high TokenAndPermUserStore issue which caused the delay in running queries. There is a scheduled job on the SQL server which runs every 1 hour and performs the DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE (‘TokenAndPermUserStore’) however this job was hung for many hours and had to be eventually killed. What are the possible reasons that a DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE gets hung for so long. Can the incoming queries cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer looks like you are likely exercising a bug in sqlserver 2005.

Longer answer this issue seems to happen when an application uses lots of adhoc queries.  This [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927396) from Microsoft seems to be a very close match. Advice includes patching your server and limiting adhoc queries.

Learning more about what is eating up your buffer is a good learning experience, related to your problem is discussed [here](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/do-you-have-hidden-cache-problems)
The queries mentioned above would let you measure how much space TokenAndPermUserStore is taking, 10 megs begin to worry, 50 meg + you likely have a problem

Hopefully you can patch your box soon...

Answer (score 0):

Never a good idea to run DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE as a maintenance job.  Maybe once off.  So you having Caching issues.  As A DBA I will check.

1) When last was you Statistics updated.

2) The Fragmentation on my Indexes.

3) Also what causes a lot of Caching issues and lot of DBAs, is that lovely ad-hoc queries.  There are DMV scripts to help with ad-hoc queries.

4) SSMS has a cool report tools, for the HIGH CPU and IO for Stored Procedures, investigate that.

There could many issues to solve your Caching issues instead of clearing it using DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE. For everything has to re-compile again.

Comment: Based on your comments, I think you're confusing `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE` with `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`…